# Continue only if ENTER button pressed else ask for Enter button again

Tags: java

i am trying to do  "Press Enter To Deal Cards to Player Hands" in my class.
but that implement not working as userInput not a "Enter" button so if statement not working in this case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Button {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Rount1");
    System.out.println("Press Enter to Deal");
        if(userInput.equal("Enter")){
        System.out.print("yes");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(Press Enter to Deal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this can go on forever, you need an infinite loop that you can break whenever Enter is pressed.

Comment: thanks. that helps.